# onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.X.X does not contain android:exported cordova target 31

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, onesignal

The Onesignal 2.X.X plugin does not insert android:exported in the Android manifest. To solve the problem I tried to insert it in the plugin.xml file, but in the merged android manifest there are parts without android:exported.
in plugin.xml

As in the image below, the files are downloaded with AndroidManifest without android:expoted.
[ExternalLibrary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULTqO.png)

Is there any way to download this local dependency so I can embed it in the project and enter android:exported?

Answer (score 0):

last version of Cordova Onesignal plugin is 3.1.1
you should use it to avoid problem with targetsdk 31 incompatibility